Preload html data before rendering react page
I'm wondering if there is a way to preload data inside a page before actually rendering that page. (Big newbie with react here).
I'm rendering an homepage, with a title being provided by a symfony backend application.
So what is happening there is that the Home page is printed by react directly, and like ... a second later the title update itself once provided by the symfony server.
This behavior is nice when loading some elements...but as i'm planning to get mostly all elements from pages from the backend application, that means that each time i will have that delay which is not great for user.
I'm wondering if there isn't any more elegant way to handle things to remove that delay, like forcing the whole page to load only once everything is loaded inside the page ?
NB : I admit, here the example is a little bit strange as it concern a title and this could be directly handled from react, but this is just for proof of concept before going for more complex and dynamic data. Also it's more convenient for me to handle translation directly in my backend application rather than with react as it's the backend who will get the locale.
Here is the code sample of this example.

src/pages/Home.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { logout } from '../api/authService';
import axios from 'axios';

const Home = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL}/message`)
            .then(response => setMessage(response.data.message))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching message:', error));
    }, []);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        logout();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{message}</h1>
            <p>This is the homepage.</p>
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;


To address the issue of the title updating with a noticeable delay, you can preload the required data before rendering the page. This can be achieved using a combination of React Router's Loader API (introduced in React Router v6.4+), or by managing your data-fetching logic in higher-order components (HOCs), context providers, or custom hooks.
You check this blog for more information.
